# Generator polynomial of cyclic code with even words

Tags: coding-theory

If $C$ is cyclic code with generator polynomial $g(x)$ and $D$ is subset of $C$ consisting of only even-weight vectors from $C$, what is generator polynomial of $D$ in terms of $g(x)$?

I can manage to show that $D$ is indeed cyclic code, but I don't know it's generator polynomial. I know it is polynomial of smallest degree that is in ideal which corresponds $D$, but how do I determine it in terms of $g(x)$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. In the long run you are encouraged to learn MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. I tried helping you this time although I am a bit unsure of how the big letters right, please let me know if I got them wrong. You write the typesetting code in between snippets delimited by $$ signs.

Comment: Thank you. I will use it in future.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we are working over $\Bbb F_2$.

If all the code-words already have even weight then the generator polynomial remains $g(X)$.

Otherwise, consider $(1+X)g(X)$. That corresponds to an even-weight
word, doesn't it? Can we have a polynomial of smaller degree than that giving rise to an even-weight word?

Comment: I think that you are right. $(1+x)g(x)$ is even-weight word obviously, and it is in D also, because it is ideal (I can consider $n \geq 2$). There shouldn't be polynomial with smaller degree than this one. Thank you very much!